# Evaluate mathjax (TeX) expression PHP

Tags: php, math, mathjax

I use Mathjax to display math expressions.
Now I need to evaluate simple expressions like `\sqrt[3]{8} + 2^{6-2}*[3*(-3) + 4*9]`. I don't need to calculate equations and draw a graph for functions (like WolframAlpha), just value of these expressions.

I've tried to preg_replace_callback  to rewrite it to PHP pow (root as fractions) and then use eval (evil :)) to compute, but didn't work as I wanted and I spent lot of time with that.

I wonder if there's any cleaner way or some simple computing engine that can do it? Any ideas?

Comment: You need to write a Mathjax parser. I doubt it can be handled easily with just regular expressions.

Comment: Well, how do I do that? What's "parser" different than the rewriting by regexp? Sorry, Im new to the terminology

Comment: A parser is a program that understands the language and translates it to another form, or performs the instructions that it describes.

Comment: Regular expressions are much more limited in the patterns they can match and rewrite.

Comment: You can use .replace to change Mathjax to js math. eg `/sqrt{x}{y}` => `Math.sqrt(x,y)` then eval it.

Comment: @typeof null: thats exactly, what I've tried before I started looking for another solution. I'm trying in PHP. Is using JS better for me?

Comment: Well, it's not solution for PHP, even if it can communicate together. I'll try to improve my simple PHP mathjax regexp translate and maybe make some parser when I get the experience. Thank you for advices

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: https://www.bersling.com/2017/01/22/mathjax-parser-for-html-strings/